# String not printing in C. Even when using '\0' character

Tags: c

I'm trying to reverse an input in c.

```
Input: Hello World

Output: dlroW olleH

Actual Output:
```

I've tested the code with putchar and it seems like it's placing the correct characters in the correct position, however it does not output anything. The code is below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLEN 1000

int getLine(char s[]); 
void reverse(char r[], char s[], int len);

int main()
{
    char string[MAXLEN];                
    char reversed[MAXLEN];
    int len;

    while((len = getLine(string)) != 0)
    {
           reverse(reversed, string, len);
           printf("%s\n", reversed);
    }
    return 0;
}

int getLine(char line[])
{
    int i, c;
    i = 0; 
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
          line[i] = c;
          i++;
    }

    line[i + 1] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void reverse(char r[], char s[], int len)
{
    int i;

    i  = 0;
    while(len >= 0)
    {
           r[i++] = s[len--];
    }
    r[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Are you placing the null byte at the end of the string into the first character, thus making the (reversed) string of zero length?

Comment: `line[i + 1] = '\0';` --> `line[i] = '\0';`

Comment: You also seem to be (un)lucky that `string` is zeroed for you — if I add `memset(string, 'X', MAXLEN - 1);` before the loop (and `#include <string.h>` before `main()`, then I see an `X` and a reversed string.

Comment: Hmm, I tried adding memset and it didn't change anything. Thank you for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 obvious problems at least:

1. As mentioned in comments, you need to use `line[i] = '\0';` rather than `line[i + 1] = '\0'` for terminating null.
2. In `reverse()` function, you need to use `r[i++] = s[--len];` rather than `r[i++] = s[len--];`. If you don't, you will have invalid memory access.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what `getLine()` means by *length*.  Is it the number of characters inserted into the array, or the number of characters excluding the '\0' that terminates the string.  This is what code comments are for:

```
int getLine(char line[])
{
    int i = 0, c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        line[i++] = c;
    }

    line[i] = '\0';

    return i; // return array length, not counting final \0
}
```

Whichever you decide, this cannot make sense:

```
r[i++] = s[len--];
```

In one case you'd be putting the string termination character '\0' as the first character of the new string, always returning an empty string, or in the other case you would be copying garbage memory into the new string.  From a 0-index-based array perspective, *length* should mean one beyond the last index.  So the last item in the array should be `s[len - 1]`.  Rather than count down on `len`, I suggest you instead count up on `i` until it reaches `len`:

```
void reverse(char r[], const char s[], size_t length)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (i < length)
    {
        r[i] = s[length - 1 - i];
        i++;
    }

    r[i] = '\0';
}
```